# How to locate table when no Id defined for the table in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been searching on the Internet for answer, seems no luck.

The problem here is I try to locate the following dynamic table which doesn't have id defined for the table:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <table class="table table-striped data-table">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th dt-bSortable="false">Name</th>
            <th dt-bSortable="false">ID</th>
            <th dt-bSortable="false">Email</th>
       </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


            <tr>
                <td>NameA</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>nameA@test.com</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>NameB</td>
                <td>222</td>
                <td>nameB@test.com</td>
            </tr>
                ...
```

What I need which is based on a given ID, I could find the corresponding Name and Email. But first, I should locate the table. I tried the following ways, but none of them are working:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("table table-striped data-table"));
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped data-table']"));
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.table-striped"));
```

I also tried to directly fetch all the rows by:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped data-table']/tbody/tr"));
```

But `rows.isEmpty()` always returns true.

Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The xpath `//table[@class='table table-striped data-table']/tbody/tr` worked in my test.  Is the div contained within a `frame` or `iframe`?

Comment: I could not find 'frame' or 'iframe' from the html source, but the table is generated in a popup dialog.

Comment: What does findElements give you?

Comment: It gives java exceptions, and return nothing when I try to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.table-striped"));
```

to work, since this means, 'find the table element with the class table-striped'. If, however, you were intending to 'find the element with the class table and the class table-striped' (which it looks like you are based on your other attempts), the command would be

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table.table-striped"));
```

Note the extra '.'.